# Gitlab's artifacts zip file is empty

Tags: docker, gitlab, robotframework, gitlab-ci, artifacts

I am trying to run the Robot Framework Tests in a Gitlab CI and download the generated report as an artifact. So far, I have succeeded running the tests in the pipeline and generate the artifact, but the generated zip is empty. What do I miss?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ppodgorsek/robot-framework:latest

COPY resources /opt/robotframework/resources
COPY tests /opt/robotframework/tests
COPY libs /opt/robotframework/libs
```

And this is my stage in the gitlab-ci.yml:

```
run robot tests dev:
  variables:
    # more variables
    ROBOT_OPTIONS: "--variable ENV:dev -e FAIL -e PENDING"
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  stage: run-robot-tests
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - mkdir -p reports
    # mode docker run commands
    - docker -H $DOCKER_HOST run --rm --network localnet --env "ROBOT_OPTIONS=${ROBOT_OPTIONS}" -v reports:/opt/robotframework/reports --name robot $CONTAINER_DEV_IMAGE
  artifacts:
    name: ${CI_JOB_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    paths:
      - reports/
    when: always
  tags:
    - d-i-d
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
```

I have omitted some details that are specific to our project.
But just to give you an idea of our set-up, we are pulling the docker image ppodgorsek/robot-framework and we run with it the tests against another docker container that runs the front-end of our project. To make sure that all containers are on the same network we are using docker-in-docker. In the same network lives also our back-end container and our db.

This is the tail of my job's output.

```
==============================================================================
Tests                                                                 | PASS |
3 critical tests, 3 passed, 0 failed
3 tests total, 3 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /opt/robotframework/reports/output.xml
Log:     /opt/robotframework/reports/log.html
Report:  /opt/robotframework/reports/report.html
Uploading artifacts...
reports/: found 1 matching files                   
Trying to load /builds/automation/system-tests.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE ... 
Dialing: tcp gitlab.surfnet.nl:443 ...             
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=42435 responseStatus=201 Created token=g8cWYYun
Job succeeded
```

You can see the console output from running the tests and then you can see where robot stores the generated output.
Next it shows that the artifact is generated, which it is, only problem is that is empty.

Comment: Can you add a job log?

Comment: I have included the output in my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was indeed very close. People from the Robot Framework community pointed me to the right direction! :D

The problem was in the command:

```
 - docker -H $DOCKER_HOST run --rm --network localnet --env "ROBOT_OPTIONS=${ROBOT_OPTIONS}" -v reports:/opt/robotframework/reports --name robot $CONTAINER_DEV_IMAGE
```

and more specifically, on the relative path for the volume:

`-v reports:/opt/robotframework/reports`

Thus, the solution was using an absolute path:

`-v $PWD/reports:/opt/robotframework/reports`

Comment: Were you able to use the output file and extract the value from it. ? I have a requirement where I need to use the value of successful run (from output.xml) to my next execution.